# Missing Application Extension Section for OSX

Tags: macos, cocoa, xcode6, osx-yosemite

I have Xcode 6.0.1 installed. When I open an existing Cocoa app and added a new target (by File>New>Target) I can see the application extension section for IOS but not in OSX section which is what I need.

[image]

Any feedback will be appreciated.

Comment: OS X applications don't have the concept of extensions that iOS 8 applications have. What are you trying to build?

Comment: I am trying to add a today widget for OSX. I checked some sites and there are many people who has Application extension section also in OSX project templates. For example check the first image on apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionCreation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH5-SW1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, I found the reason by myself. Version of my Xcode was 6.0.1 and now I can see Application extensions also for OSX after upgrading it to 6.1.

Application Extensions are available for IOS in 6.0.1 but OSX version was not included. This was also not mentioned in Apple's documentation. I don't know why.

I hope this helps someone...

Answer (score 0):

I have Xcode 6.1.1 and it shows up for me.

[image]